# Debugging JSON using Chrome's Dev Tools

Tags: json, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

How do I access the ***results*** array from the following page using Google Chrome's console?

> twitter.com/search.json?q=stackexchange

I keep getting this error:

> ReferenceError: results is not defined

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If what you really want is to browse this result set in a convinient way, just install [one of JSON viewers for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/json) (preferably [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)).

If you don't want to install any plugins, just run this:

```
JSON.parse($('.webkit-line-content').innerHTML);
```

in the console on page:

```
view-source:https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=stackexchange
```

Comment: +1 I have JSONview already installed. But I also want to learn how to use Chrome's console to access these objects. For example, I thought (wrongly apperantly) that I could access the array results with this command in the Console: results.some_sibling

Comment: `results` is not defined on the global object (`window`), as what you are looking at is just a bunch of text. It has never been parsed with `JSON.parse()`, which Konrad suggests.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov is correct, Chrome is getting result from https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=stackexchange and just displays it as a normal text file - it's never parsed, there is no JSON object created anywhere.

Comment: +1 Thank you Konrad and Alexander. I am beginning to understand JSON better now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.debug()` function in chrome console tab.
example:

```
console.debug(results)
```

Comment: +1 I got the same error with console.debug(results) "ReferenceError: results is not defined"

Comment: you can debug only the global variable. try this: `console.debug(__screenCapturePageContext__)`

Comment: Hmmmm, I thought I could access all variables from Chrome's console?

Comment: Yes. You can type: `console.debug(`, then CTRL+Space, you will see all accessible objects and methods.

Comment: +1 cool. I really enjoyed accessing these variables from the console, wish I could access "results" because its so much easier for me to understand JSON.